# How to subscribe for messages sent from Service Worker in the angular way?

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have this snippet that is already working:

```js
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    try {
        await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/my-sw.js");
        navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", event => {
            if (event.data.someProperty) {
                // do something
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Registration failed with ${error}`);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In `my-sw.js` I have a piece of code which sends the message to the client to take action on:

```js
if (someCondition) {
    const client = await self.clients.get(clientId);

    if (client) {
        client.postMessage({ someProperty: true });
    }
}
```

I tried to do it in the Angular way:

```js
imports: [
    // ...
    ServiceWorkerModule.register("my-sw.js", { enabled: true })
]
```

This registers my SW but I didn't find a way to subscribe for messages sent from the SW. Tried using the `SwPush` service but it didn't work for me

How can I do something like this?

Comment: See this: https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwPush#usage-notes

Comment: Thanks @R.Richards! I updated the post with a piece of code I have in the SW, does `SwPush` works for that?

Comment: @R.Richards Your link is about WebPush nor what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd Create a service which can be imported by whatever other service or component :

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class MyService {

    messages$ = new Subject<MessageEvent<any>();

    constructor() {
        if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
            try {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register("/my-sw.js");
                navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", event => {
                    messages$.next(event)
                    if (event.data.someProperty) {
                        // do something
                    }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Registration failed with ${error}`);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the subject will broadcast to every subscriber.

Comment: Thanks! But in this case, I was more interested in if it's possible to translate my current snippet to the "Angular way"

Comment: @dcg that's the "angular" way

Comment: Oh OK, I thought it would be using the `SeviceWorkerModule` or any other feature. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: @dcg you can register it that way, but you'll still need to listen to the messages using that kind of service !